Notation for the pairwise union of the elements of two sets of sets
Is there some special notation or name for this operation of taking the pairwise union of the elements of two sets of sets $S$ and $P$?
$$S\ \dot{\cup}\ P := \big\{s \cup p \mid (s,p) \in S \times P\big\}$$
E.g., $\big\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\} \big\}\ \dot{\cup} \ \big\{\{4,5\}, \{6,7\} \big\} = \big\{\{1,2,4,5\}, \{1,2,6,7\}, \{3,4,5\}, \{3,4,6,7\} \big\}$.
The term "unordered Cartesian product" seems to be related but different in that the set $\{s,p\}$ rather than the pair $(s,p)$ is considered, though not the union $s \cup p$.

I have not seen this personally, but nothing is stopping you from defining it like you have and including the definition in whatever it is you are working on.
